# Compton effect in daily life

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, scattering

In the Compton effect, a photon strikes a particle (electron) and changes its wavelength.

Does Compton effect occur in day-to-day life too? If yes, then how can we identify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Compton scattering involves the recoil of the electron that the photon scatters from, which takes away some of the energy. This requires that the electrons are essentially free, or if they are not free that their ionization energy is much less than the energy of the incoming photon.

Visible light has insufficient energy to even ionize most materials, so under ordinary conditions it is not involved in Compton scattering.

Even if it were, shifts in wavelength due to the Compton effect are at most $5~\rm pm$. While this is easily detected with high energy photons, visible light has wavelengths of hundreds of thousands of $\rm pm$, and so this effect would be very difficult to measure.

Comment: What about the role of the angular change in scattering? The impulse transmitted to the electron has got direction?